# create own bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

i am writing my thesis in latex,i am biginner in latex,i use `\bibliographystyle{}` and `\bibliography{filename}`, but when i see the requirement of my university ,they ask for another format, example[image]

so I can't use `\bibliographystyle{}`, because the style is not known, I didn't find on the internet any style like in example. what I need to change to get the style like the example .thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package?

Comment: no,but if will fix the problem i will learn about it ,my temlpate thesis has \\bibliographystyle{} and \bibliography{filename},

Comment: The `makebst` presents a menu-driven interface for creating new **b**ibliography **st**yle files -- the arguments of `\bibliographystyle` -- from scratch.

Comment: Old question, but for other visitors: maybe `\bibliographystyle{plaindin}` would be sufficient.